# Is 'dot slash' (./) mandatory when a module in Node.js is required?

Tags: node.js, module

I'm learning Node.js and writing a simple module using the Visual Studio 2015 Node.JS extension.

I know `./` means 'look for the file in the same directory'. But in most systems I've seen (say, `#include` in C++) the forwarding `./` is optional. I've tried to remove it but it turns out Node.js cannot find modules without the prefix. For me it seems ugly, so is it really mandatory? If yes, why?

Regards,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `require('./script_name')`, you can include another JS within the same folder, as you know already.

When you `require('module_name')` without the `./`, Node.JS looks at the `node_modules` folder for a module with this name. Optionally, you can call it's public methods or pass it arguments.

Comment: Great, thank you. But it follows to another question: is there a way to set the `node_modules` path in Visual Studio? I've tried 'Working directory' in the project properties, but it seems to be something different...

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Visual Studio for years. Somebody else will have to answer this.

Comment: Still don't know how to use custom folders, but have discovered I can just create a folder and rename it to `node_modules` in the project root directory and modules will be loaded from there.

Comment: You should really use the node_modules folder only for dependencies defined in your package.json. Even though it's possible to put there other stuff, it's just not a clean approach.